# What are the Y_TFT, C_TFT and BL_EN pins used for?

Tags: schematics, lcd

The display controller board for Philips PET 714 has a 16 pin connector like this:

[image: 16 pin connector for display controller]

What are the Y_TFT, C_TFT and BL_EN pins used for?

Reference:
[Service Manual which has the schematics](https://manualzz.com/doc/19695498/service-manual-dvd-portable-player--pet714-pet718)

Comment: BL_EN: Backlight enable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BL_EN is a backlight enable signal used to turn the TFT panel backlight on and off.

The Y_TFT and C_TFT do not seem to be connected anywhere so these pins seem unused - but it might be an error. Based on the name they would be the Luma and Chroma signals of an S-Video interface to deliver the picture to TFT driver board.

Comment: Nice. I saw the same thing in the diagram, but gave up as I wasn't going to read the whole thing. +1